# System Shutdown with LXTerminal

Tags: lubuntu

How can I shutdown Lubuntu using LXTerminal?

I've tried with `halt` or `shutdown now` but they doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo shutdown -h now`. This should work.